# what is debounceTime(), buffer(), throttle() methods in bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am reading official docs in `bloc` in flutter.

It says:

**Another area in which Bloc excels over Cubit is when we need to take advantage of reactive operators such as `buffer`, `debounceTime`, `throttle` etc.**

Could you explain me in more detail because I don't very much get why they are used even though I have read several articles.

Answer (score 4):

**[Buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html)** - periodically gather items emitted by an Observable into bundles and emit these bundles rather than emitting the items one at a time.

Could for instance be to buffer logs and send that in chunks, instead of one line at a time.

**[Debounce](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html)** - only emit an item from an Observable if a particular timespan has passed without it emitting another item.

For instance to avoid "hammering" on a button, as this is a common use case with physical buttons.

**[Throttle](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Throttle)** - provides a sort of protection against sequences that produce values at variable rates and sometimes too quickly.

A great application of the Throttle method would be to use it with a live search like "Google Suggest". While the user is still typing we can hold off on the search. Once there is a pause for a given period, we can execute the search with what they have typed.